# Why is there SyntaxError to this equal sign when printing to a file?

Tags: python, printing, terminal

I'm using Terminal on macbook to print data into an open file:

```
>>> out=open("test_output.txt","w")
>>> print("hello",file=out)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print("hello",file=out)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why would there be SyntaxError and how to fix it? Anyway, the same scripts runs well in IDLE.

PS:

It's Python 2.7, I've actually installed Python 3.5, but the packages of NetworkX and Matplotlib are both automatically installed to libraries of Python 2.7, so that's the platform I'm using while doing social network analysis.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: What are you actually trying print ? Are you trying to print file object ?

Comment: The `print()` function is a Python 3 feature; it is available in Python 2.6+ too (and is generally recommended) if the file begins with `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: @Antti - minor clarification: you can use the `print()` *syntax* going back at least as far as Python 2.5, but it was only changed to *act* like a function in 3, as well as when the `__future__` module from 2.6 onward. like you said.

Comment: it's python 2.7, thanks to Antti, it works!!

Comment: @MattDMo this was specifically about keyword arguments, the keyword arguments are not supported for `print` the statement.

Answer (score 6):

Before I begin to answer your question regarding the syntax error, I first need to tell you that there are *two* versions of Python. Python 2 and Python 3. Python 3 is the supposed future of the language and the version that is running in your IDLE installation. Python 2 is the version that you are using when you invoke `python` in the command line.

There isn't much of a difference between the two, but `print` is certainly one of them. `print` is a *function* in Python 3, but a *statement* in python 2. What does that even mean? In Python 2, print does not return anything, it just pushes data out into the command line. In Python 3, it actually *returns* something. This means that in Python 3, you can do something like this:

```
a = print("thing")
```

In python 2, if we were to do the same thing, we would get a syntax error:

```
>>> a = print("thing")
  File "<input>", line 1
    a = print("thing")
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Because `print` is a function in Python 3, you can provide it additional arguments. That is why you can do something like `print("thing", out=file)`. In python 2, the equivalent would be `print>>file, "thing"`.

So, you have a few options now. You can change your `.py` file to reflect the correct syntax in Python 2. You can use python 3 to run the file instead of python 2 using `python3` to invoke python in the command line.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the above code to be portable in python-2 (2.6 onwards) then you need to  import the print_function from [future module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html)

Example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
out=open("test_output.txt","w")
print("hello",file=out)
```

This [article](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) lists the difference in usage of print statement in python-2.X vs print function in python-3.x.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using your Terminal to do

```
$ python filename.py
```

I all but guarantee that you're actually running Python3 code (`print(...)`) in Python2. Try instead doing:

```
$ py -3 filename.py
```

See if that doesn't fix your issue.

To confirm, you can do:

```
$ python --version
```